# rest framework serializer fails on POST request with models in OneToMany Relationship

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models 
**Apartment Model**

```
class Apartment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(LandOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    property_size = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null =False, blank = False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False )
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False )
    category = models.ManyToManyField(HouseCategory)
    no_of_house = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False )
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False )
```

**House Model**

```
class House(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(HouseCategory, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    cost = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null=False, blank = False)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    features = models.ManyToManyField(HouseFeatures)
    occupied = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

Their serializers
**ApartmentSerializer**

```
class PropertySerializer(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.Apartment
    fields = '__all__'
```

**HouseSerializer**

```
class HouseSerializer(ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.House
    fields = [
            'description',
            'apartment',
            'category',
            'occupied',
            'cost',
            'total',
            'features',
    ]
    depth = 1
```

A Get request to the following view

```
class Listing(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [ permissions.AllowAny ]
    # permission_classes = [ permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly ]
    serializer_class = serializers.HouseSerializer
    queryset = House.objects.all()
```

I get this JSON which my designed output

```
{
        "description": "",
        "apartment": {
            "id": 1,
            "property_size": "30Ha",
            "location": "Nairobi",
            "name": "Real Estate Apartment",
            "town": "Nairobi",
            "no_of_house": 4,
            "year": 2019,
            "owner": 1,
            "category": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Single Room"
        },
        "occupied": 2,
        "cost": "40000",
        "total": 5,
        "features": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Source of Water"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "wifi availability"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Swimming pool available"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem is when I send a POST request to the same view I get "NOT NULL constraint failed: House.apartment_id". The JSON sent with POST request is

```
{
        "apartment": 10,
        "cost": "40000",
        "description": "",
        "occupied": 2,
        "total": 5,
        "category": 1,
        "features": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
```

}

What I intended the view to do with the post request was to save a new house with the information given and set the related field apartment to be the id I sent with the JSON payload

Comment: On POST request, I think the Serializer is trying to also create an apartment instead of creating a reference to an existing apartment in the house table. Am not sure how to tell it to do just this - create a reference to an existing apartment on the current model (House)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this question, on the property serializer, I overrode the method `def to_reperesentation(self, instance)` to this

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    self.fields['owner'] = LandOwnerSerializer(read_only = True)
    self.fields['category'] = HouseCategorySerializer(read_only = True, many = True)

    return super(PropertySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

And in the HouseSerializer I also did the same ( overriding the to_representation) method and added a bit of modification to look like this

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    self.fields['apartment'] = PropertySerializer(read_only = True, )
    return super(HouseSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

Now it's working just fine, adding a house only takes the Id of the target apartment while fetching fetches the apartment details. Thanks all for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Serializer like this:

```
class HouseSerializer(ModelSerializer):
apartment = PropertySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

class Meta:
    model = models.House
    fields = [
            'description',
            'apartment',
            'category',
            'occupied',
            'cost',
            'total',
            'features',
    ]
```

Comment: Same error, Integrity Issues, Error- django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: House.apartment_id

Comment: Have tried overriding the validate method of the house serializer though, the apartment field is not part of the attributes the method receives.  This is output of print statement in the validate method. OrderedDict([('description', ''), ('category', <HouseCategory: Single Room>), ('occupied', 2), ('cost', '40000'), ('total', 5), ('features', [<HouseFeatures: Source of Water>, <HouseFeatures: wifi availability>, <HouseFeatures: Swimming pool available>])]

Comment: am using Django version 4.0.1

Comment: I have modified the HouseSerializer to only include the model and the fields attribute to look like this fields = '__all__' . It works fine for both get and post request, Problem arises when I add the attribute depth=1